# migrate to PKCS12 (keystore uses a proprietary format)The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect

Tags: android, keystore, android-keystore

**Warning:
The JKS keystore uses a proprietary format. It is recommended to migrate to PKCS12 which is an industry standard format using "keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\Hp.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\Hp.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12".**

and when I was going to migrate to PKCS12 then face problem

**C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin>"keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore C:\Users\Hp.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore C:\Users\Hp.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12"
The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.**

I checked my directory is correct but I face a problem

Answer (score 1):

Remove the quotes and the "C:" and Add a trailing slash to your directory .e.g it should be like this

`C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-10.0.1\bin>keytool -importkeystore -srckeystore \User\Hp\.android\debug.keystore -destkeystore \Users\Hp\.android\debug.keystore -deststoretype pkcs12`

Tested it,that should work